# ajax post API URL not working on form onClick button

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, api

I'm trying to create a form to Add new users into the website. I created HTMl form and trying to connect 'http://localhost/r/svr/user.php?action=add&name=Aa&email=ash@gmail.com&role=1&pass=1234' post API to send data to the database.

**HTML file**

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
          <button onclick="openForm()">Add new</button>
          <br>
          <br>
          <div class="form-popup" id="myForm">

          <form method="post" action="dashboard-users.php" class="form-container">
            <h3>Add user</h3>

            <label for="name"><b>Name</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" id="username" name="username" required>

            <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" id="email" name="email" required>
            <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" id="psw" name="psw" required>

            <label for="role"><b>Role</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Student/Teacher" id="role" name="role" required>

            <button type="submit" class="btn" onclick="addUser()">Add</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
          </form>
          </div>
```

**JS file**

```
function addUser(){
    var name = $("input#username").val();   //comes from a drop-down select box whose id="cmbGender" on the html form.
    var email = $("input#email").val();   //comes from an input textbox whose id="txtDOB" on the html form.
    var password = $("input#psw").val();  //comes from an input textbox whose id="txtHeight" on the html form.
    var role = $("input#role").val();  //comes from a drop-down select box whose id="cmbCountries" on the html form.

    var role_id = '';

    if(role == 'student'){
        role_id = '3';
    }else if(role == 'teacher'){
        role_id = '2';
    }else{
        role_id = '1';
    }

    //now create an array to hold all the data in one structure
    var dataArray = {
      "name":name,
      "email":email,
      "pass":password,
      "role":role_id
    };

    //now invoke jQuery to finish of the job:
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: ".http://localhost/r/svr/user.php?action=add&",
      data: {u_data : JSON.stringify(dataArray)},
      cache: false,
      success: function(svr_resp){
        if(svr_resp == '1'){
          alert("Data successfully captured on the server.");
          //you may do more things here, depending on your needs...
        } else {
          alert("Error: Data not captured on the server.");
          //you may do more things here, depending on your needs...
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

when i click Add button it will not send data to the database. I'll appreciate if someone could help me to resolve it

**Update**

user.php

```
<?php
require_once 'db_user.php';
require_once 'util.php';
$action = process_request_and_get_action();
info(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, $action, reset_pass($_REQUEST));

switch ($action) {
  case ACTION_READ:
    db_user_read($_REQUEST);
    break;
  case ACTION_ADD:
    db_user_add($_REQUEST);
    break;  
  case ACTION_MOD:
    update_user_profile($_REQUEST);
    break;
  default:
    exit(fail_return(ERR_UNKNOWN_ACTION, false));
}
?>
```

*db_user_add()*

```
function  db_user_add($args){

   $role = $args['role'];

   add_basic_info($args);
   add_role_user($args);

   if ( $role == 2){  
      add_teachers_details($args);
   }
}

function add_basic_info($args){

   $name = $args['name'];
   $email = $args['email'];
   $password = $args['pass'];

   $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (
      `id`, `name`, `email`, `password`, `created_at`, `updated_at`
    ) VALUE (
      NULL, '$name', '$email', sha1('$password'), NULL, NULL
    )";

    debug(__FILE__,__FUNCTION__,__LINE__, $query);
    db_execute($query);  
}


function add_role_user($args){

   $id = get_user_id($args);
   $role = $args['role'];

   $query = "INSERT INTO `role_user`(
      `role_id`, `user_id`
   ) VALUE (
      $role, $id
   )";
   debug(__FILE__,__FUNCTION__,__LINE__, $query);
   db_execute($query);  
}

function get_user_id($args){

   $name = $args['name'];

   $query = "select id from users where name  = '$name'
   ";

   $result = db_execute($query);
   debug(__FILE__,__FUNCTION__,__LINE__, $result);
   return $result['0']['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
url: ".http://localhost/r/svr/user.php?action=add&",
```

Should not start with a `.`. It should be:

```
url: "http://localhost/r/svr/user.php?action=add&",
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it works. But it added only the password. Name,email and other details were not added into the database. Could you help me to resolve it?

Comment: @F.A.SULAIMAN replace `JSON.stringify(dataArray)` with `dataArray` and try that

Comment: Still it gives empty rows

Comment: Can you post user.php?

Comment: I have updated the question .kindly request you to view it